# How to skip auto login page and redirect to social login site?

Tags: amazon-cognito, linkedin-api, openid-connect, auth0

How to skip auto login page and directly redirect in to social login site?
Is it possible to skip authO login page and directly navigate to gmail or Linkedin page?

I have used AWS cognito for linkedin identity provider as OIDC.

myApp --> authO Login page --> social web site login page --> Myapp

i want to skip authO login page .

Comment: you want to skip the cognito login page? question is not clear. you are using Auth0 or Cognito? I understand  that you want to directly goes to LinkedIn. but how aws cognito related to this?

Comment: I have the same Question, In my case I have one application in which users login using the aws cognito credentials, Now we have implemented SSO auto login in other application in which user can redirect from 1st application. Now before redirect on 2nd application it again ask for the login credentials and login page appers.

Is there any way I can skip that login page to access 2nd application as I have already login into 1st app using the aws cognito credentials.